# Compute the number of ways the frog can start at point (0,0) and end at point (5,5)

Tags: combinatorics

I recently gave an online assignment on quantitative aptitude, I am getting 120 ways but I am not confident about it.

A frog is trying to get from point A to point B without overshooting, but he can only move up or right. he always alternates his step sizes between moving 1 unit in a single direction and moving 2 units in a single direction. Compute the number of ways the frog can start at point A(0,0) and end at point B(5,5)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi, please let us know how you decided on 120 ways.  Have you tried checking that your method works? You can explicitly count out the paths. If there are too many, maybe try the paths from $(0,0)$ to (say) $(3,3)$ and see if your method gives the correct count.

Answer (score 3):

> **Statement 1**. The length of the frog’s path is always equal to $10$ units.

Indeed, the frog must move $5$ units to the right and $5$ units up in some order. And $5+5=10.$

> **Statement 2**. The starts with the $1$ unit jump.

The frog covers $3$ units in two consecutive jumps. And $10$ modulo $3$ is $1$. In other words, if the frog started with a $2$ units jump, then it would cover the distance $(2+1)+(2+1)+(2+1)=9$ or $(2+1)+(2+1)+(2+1)+2=11$ units, but not $10$.

> **Statement 3**. The frog made exactly $7$ jumps.

It’s because the sum $1+2+1+2+1+2+1=10$ has exactly $7$ summands.

> **Statement 4**. The frog made at least $3$ vertical and at least $3$ horizontal jumps.

If the frog made less than $3$ horizontal jumps, then it moved at most $2\times 2=4$ units to the right, which is not enough. The same for vertical jumps.

All the possible paths split into two groups. One group consists of the paths with $3$ horizontal and $4$ vertical paths. The other, vice versa, consists of the paths with $4$ horizontal and $3$ vertical paths.

> **Statement 5**. There is the same number of paths in each group.

The groups have the same number of paths because there is a natural symmetry between those two groups of paths. We just change all the horizontal jumps to the vertical ones, and vice versa. For example, the path HVVHVHV corresponds to the path VHHVHVH, where H is a horizontal jump and V is a vertical jump.

Thus, we only need to count the number of ways in the first group and multiply it by $2$.

> **Statement 6**. Every path from the first group has one $1$-unit and two $2$-units horizontal jumps.

This is the only way to get the sum $5$ with $3$ summands equal to $1$ or $2$: $5=2+2+1.$

> **Statement 7**. Every path from the first group has three $1$-unit and one $2$-unit vertical jumps.

The only way to represent $5$ as a sum of $4$ summands equal to $1$ or $2$ is $5=2+1+1+1$.

> **Statement 8**. There are $12$ paths in the first group.

Indeed, we must choose which of the three horizontal jumps is a $1$-unit jump ($3$ ways to do so) and choose which of the four vertical jumps is a $2$-units jumps ($4$ ways to do so). So $3\times 4=12$ ways to choose a path overall.

> **Statement 9**. The answer to your problem is $24$.

Since $12\times 2=24$.